# function twististing the arguments

Tags: c, function, arguments

I created a function called 'foo', and I'm calling her firstly in the main with the arguments row=0 and col=0. The first thing the function does(I did that for the debug) is to print row and col. From some reason the the first thing that the progrram prints is:

```
1 1
1 0
```

and just than `0 0`.
When it should print first her first argument(0 0) first, does someone know why is that?

Tnx, Dean

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size (3)
#include "List.h"
void foo(List *addit,List *list, int row,int col,char from,int sum,int array[][size])
{
    printf("%d ",col);
    printf("%d\n",row);
    if(row==size-1&&col==size-1){
            add(addit,row*10+col);
            nested(list,addit,sum+array[row][col]);
            return;
        }
    if(row!=size-1&&from!='d'){
        addit=(clone(addit));
        foo(addit,list,row+1,col,'u',sum+array[row][col],array);
        add(addit,row*10+col);
    }
    if(row!=0&&from!='u'){
            addit=(clone(addit));
            foo(addit,list,row-1,col,'d',sum+array[row][col],array);
            add(addit,row*10+col);
    }
    if(col!=0&&from!='l'){
            addit=(clone(addit));
            foo(addit,list,row,col-1,'r',sum+array[row][col],array);
            add(addit,row*10+col);
    }
    if(col!=size-1&&from!='r'){
            addit=(clone(addit));
            foo(addit,list,row,col+1,'l',sum+array[row][col],array);
            add(addit,row*10+col);
    }
}
int max(List* lst)
{
    Node *node=lst->first;
    int var=0;
    while(node!=NULL){
        if(node->info>var)
            var=node->info;
        node=node->next;    
    }
    return var;
}
int main()
{
    List * l1=(List*)(malloc(sizeof(List)));;
    make_list(l1,0);
    int array[size][size];
    unsigned i,k;
    for(k=0;k<size;++k){
        for(i=0;i<size;++i){
            //scanf("%d",array[k][i])
            array[k][i]=i;
        }
    }
    List *list=(List*)(malloc(sizeof(List)));
    make_list(list,0);
    foo(list,l1,0,0,'u',0,array);
    printf("maindebug");
    printf("%d",max(l1));
}
```

and here is List.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "List.h"
#include "Node.h"
List* clone(List* l1){
    List *l2=(List*)(malloc(sizeof(List)));
    Node* node=l1->first;
    make_list(l2,node->info);
    node=node->next;
    while(node!=NULL){
        add(l2,node->info);
        node=node->next;
    }
    return l2;
}
int make_list(List* l1,int new_info)
{
    Node *node=(Node*)(malloc(sizeof(Node)));
    if(node==NULL)
        return 1;
    node->info=new_info; node->next=NULL; node->prev=NULL;
    l1->first=node;
    l1->last=node;
    l1->len=1;
    l1->sum=new_info;   
    return 0;
}
float get_avg(List* l1){
    return (float)l1->sum/l1->len;
}
int nested(List* big,List* nes, int new_info){
    Node *node=(Node*)(malloc(sizeof(Node)));
    node->info=new_info; node->next=NULL; node->prev=NULL; node->lst=nes;
    if(node==NULL)
        return 1;
    Node* temp=big->last;
    big->last=node;
    temp->next=big->last;
    (++big->len);
    big->sum+=new_info;
    return 0;
}
int add(List *l1, int new_info)
{
    Node* temp=l1->last;
    Node* node=(Node*)(malloc(sizeof(Node)));
    if(node==NULL)
        return 1;
    node->info=new_info; node->next=NULL; node->prev=temp;
    l1->last=node;
    temp->next=l1->last;
    (++l1->len);
    l1->sum+=new_info;
    return 0;
}
void del(List* l1,Node * node)
{
    int a=1;
    if(l1->len!=1)
    {
        if(node==l1->first){
            l1->first=node->next;
            Node* temp=l1->first;
            temp->prev=NULL;
            a=0;    
        }
        if(a!=0&&node==l1->last){
            l1->last=node->prev;
            Node* temp=l1->last;
            temp->next=NULL;
            a=0;
        }
        if(a!=0&&node!=l1->last&&node!=l1->first)
        {
        Node* pre=node->prev; Node* nex=node->next;
        pre->next=node->next;
        nex->prev=node->prev;
        }
    }   
    l1->sum-=node->info;
    free(node);
    --(l1->len);
}
void destruct(List* l1){
    unsigned i=0;
    for(i=1;i<=l1->len;i++){
        del(l1,l1->first);
    }
}
void printinfo(List* l1){
    unsigned i=0; 
    Node* node=l1->first;
    for(i=1;i<=l1->len;i++){
        printf("%d\n",node->info);
        node=node->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure none of the functions before `foo` is printing them?

Comment: Yes, I thought that it might be the problem too, but I went over all of the function a couple of times and they dont. Some of the weirdest problem I've ever witness.

Comment: Do you have any compiler warnings?

Comment: Can we see your `make_list()` function?

Comment: Seems unlikely. Post your `List.h`

Comment: Maybe you are compiling (or running) an old version of your program

Comment: No, but it says procces exited with return value 3221225477(not zero), you think the problem might be in the make_lits function, cause I cheacked it and it works fine, do you think it's expedient to publish make_list function?

Comment: Just a though: are you sure, you rebuilt **everything**? This kind of errors can occur when you link with stale object files.

Comment: Without more information, it seems that `make_list()` is possibly corrupting the stack or register that holds `0` and when the call to foo comes, you have `1` passed (twice) instead of `0`

Comment: I recompiled it after every change, @AlterMann

Comment: Your main does not return 0, that explains the non null exit value.

Comment: `3221225477` is `0xc0000005` in hexadecimal. That's a Windows access violation.

Comment: Why doesn't your program print "maindebug", since you have a `printf` in the program that does that ?

Comment: I cahnge it to return 0 at the end of the main and it still the same problem, what does windos access viloation means? what the problem might be?@KeithThompson

Comment: I dont know, from some reason and doesn't even get to the first if in foo@MarkLakata

Comment: Now I am guessing that `malloc()` is returning null

Comment: I wrote  if(list==NULL||l1==NULL)
 printf("malloc size");        also on every malloc in the make_list function and it doesn't sem to be the problem

Comment: I recommend doing a `make clean` or the equivalent at this point, make sure all your compiled and intermediate objects are gone, and rebuild from from source anew. Seems unlikely, but occasionally things can get out of sync, and we aren't seeing any other explanation for your described behavior.

Comment: What do you mean 'make clean' is that a command you give to the compiler? or do you mean just to reinstall the compiler?@ElchononEdelson